# How to prove $\int_M-\text{Ric}(V,V)+ |\nabla V|^2 =\int_M \frac{1}{2}|L_Vg|^2-\big(\text{div}V\big)^2$?

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, curvature, lie-derivative

$\newcommand{\Ric}{\text{Ric}}$
$\newcommand{\div}{\text{div}}$
$\newcommand{\tr}{\text{trace}}$
$\newcommand{\g}{\mathfrak{g}}$

Let $M$ be a smooth closed oriented Riemannian manifold.

I am looking for a reference (or a sketch of proof) for the following equality:

> For every vector field $V \in \Gamma(TM)$,
>   $$ \int_M-\Ric(V,V)+ |\nabla V|^2 =\int_M \frac{1}{2}|L_Vg|^2-\big(\div(V)\big)^2,$$

where $ \nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection, and all integrations are against the Riemannian volume form.

**Motivation:**

The LHS is $ \int_M \langle JV ,  V \rangle$ where $J:\Gamma(TM) \to \Gamma(TM)$ is the **Jacobi operator**, i.e.

$$
J(V)=J_{\text{id}_M}(V)=-\tr_{\g} R^{M}\big(V,(\cdot)\big)(\cdot)+\nabla^*{\nabla}V.
$$

So, the question is to prove **another formula** for the hessian of the Dirichlet energy at the identity, namely:

> $$ H(E)_{\text{id}_M}(V,V)=\int_M \langle JV ,  V \rangle=\int_M \frac{1}{2}|L_Vg|^2-\big(\div(V)\big)^2.$$

This formula is useful in showing various results regarding the stability of the identity map (for instance w.r.t to conformal variations).

I found a source claiming that there is a reference for this in "K. Yano and S. Bochner, Curvature and Betti numbers" (1953) - pg 57, but I could not find it there.

Another source cited "On harmonic and Killing vector fields, Yano" (formula 4.4) but again, I did not find it there.

Perhaps I am missing something, or having trouble with the notation (both references are from the 50's).

Comment: You should use a different name for your divergence macro - `\div` is used for the division symbol.

Comment: Anyway, the proof should be two steps: first substitute $L_V g = 2 \operatorname{Sym} \nabla V$ (you should know this formula from studying Killing fields), expand and simplify; then integrate by parts a couple times. In between the two integrations by parts you will need to commute covariant derivatives, leading to the curvature term.

Comment: What does that LHS even mean? To me the RHS is almost by definition $\operatorname{tr}(\nabla V \circ \nabla V),$ so you should be done.

Comment: Oh, you are right, so the last step is a pointwise identity: $\tr(T^2)=\sum_{ij} \langle T(e_i) ,e_j \rangle  \langle T(e_j) ,e_i \rangle$. Thanks  again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}$
$\newcommand{\Ric}{\text{Ric}}$
$\newcommand{\div}{\text{div}}$
$\newcommand{\tr}{\text{trace}}$
$\newcommand{\g}{\mathfrak{g}}$

This answer is based on Anthony Carapetis's comment.

We shall use the following identity (See equation $(3)$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559624/is-this-identity-about-the-ricci-curvature-true)):

$$\int_{\M} -\Ric(V,V)= \int_{\M} -(\div V)^2  +\tr ( \nabla V \circ \nabla V) . \tag{1}$$

Using this, the required identity
$$\int_M-\Ric(V,V)+ |\nabla V|^2 =\int_M \frac{1}{2}|L_Vg|^2-\big(\div V \big)^2,$$ reduces to

$$\int_{\M} \tr ( \nabla V \circ \nabla V)+ |\nabla V|^2 =\int_M \frac{1}{2}|L_Vg|^2. \tag{2}$$

Now, using the fact 
$$ L_Vg(X,Y)=\langle \nabla_X V,Y \rangle+\langle \nabla_Y V,X \rangle,$$

and choosing an orthonormal basis $e_i$ for $T\M$, we obtain

$$ \frac{1}{2}|L_Vg|^2=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{ij} \big(L_Vg(e_i,e_j)\big)^2=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{ij} \big(\langle \nabla_{e_i} V,e_j \rangle+\langle \nabla_{e_j} V,e_i \rangle \big)^2$$

$$ =\sum_{ij} \langle \nabla_{e_i} V,e_j \rangle^2+  \sum_{ij} \langle \nabla_{e_i} V,e_j \rangle  \langle \nabla_{e_j} V,e_i \rangle =\sum_{i} |\nabla_{e_i} V|^2+  \sum_{ij} \langle \nabla_{e_i} V,e_j \rangle  \langle \nabla_{e_j} V,e_i \rangle$$

$$ = |\nabla  V|^2+  \sum_{ij} \langle \nabla_{e_i} V,e_j \rangle  \langle \nabla_{e_j} V,e_i \rangle.$$

Using the last equation, the required result $(2)$ reduces to

$$ \int_{\M} \tr ( \nabla V \circ \nabla V)=\int_{\M} \sum_{ij} \langle \nabla_{e_i} V,e_j \rangle  \langle \nabla_{e_j} V,e_i \rangle,$$

But now the integrands are equal; This follows from a pointwise identity.
Given a linear map $T:V \to V$, $$\tr(T^2)=\sum_{ij} \langle T(e_i) ,e_j \rangle  \langle T(e_j) ,e_i \rangle,$$
where $e_i$ is an orthonormal basis. (Apply this for $T=\nabla V$).

Indeed, write $ A_{ij}:=\langle T(e_i) ,e_j \rangle$. $(A_{ij})$ is the representing matrix of $T$ w.r.t the basis $e_i$. Then

$$\sum_{ij} \langle T(e_i) ,e_j \rangle  \langle T(e_j) ,e_i \rangle=\sum_{ij} A_{ij} A_{ji}=\langle A,A^T \rangle=\tr((A^T)^TA)=\tr(A^2).$$

Since $A^2$ is the representing matrix of $T$, we deduce

$$\sum_{ij} \langle T(e_i) ,e_j \rangle  \langle T(e_j) ,e_i \rangle=\tr(T^2)$$ as required.